# Local Storage values not getting loaded in React App

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am new to React and following one of the video series available on Udemy (**React for the rest of us by Brad Schiff**). The author has provided a backend system for user login etc.
When the user logs in, the backend server sends 3 values in response to a successful login: the login token, the user name and the avatar url (a dummy image from gravatar.com). These values are then stored in local storage from where they can be displayed on the UI:

```
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", {username, password});

    if (response.data) {
        // if response contains token, set login flag to true
        props.loginFlagHandler(true);

        // save user token, username, avatar in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("username", response.data.username);
        localStorage.setItem("loginToken", response.data.token);
        localStorage.setItem("avatar", response.data.avatar); }
```

Now, when I log in and the UI updates, the values received from server are successfully stored in local storage of my browser, but they are not getting reflected on the UI. The avatar image doesn't load and the Welcome message that should display the username doesn't work as expected (see the 1st image below). The Welcome message should read "Hello <*username*>, your feed is empty"

However, once I hit refresh, both the Avatar Image and the User name get displayed as they should, on their relevant place. (refer 2nd image).

In both the cases, I am referring to the localStorage variable as below:

```
<img className="small-header-avatar" src={localStorage.getItem("avatar")} />
```

And:

```
<h2 className="text-center">
  Hello <strong>{localStorage.getItem("username")}</strong>, your feed is empty.
</h2>
```

I think this should be a noob thing that I'm missing here. Nevertheless, thanks in advance:

[image: Empty user name on welcome message and avatar image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is - component does not refresh itself because it has no reason to do so. Data in local storage has been changed, but Your component doesn't know about that change. Manual refresh forces component to render itself again.

Comment: can you provide the code of your react component?

Comment: Does the page refresh and redirect to the auth route upon successful http request?

Comment: If your app is using a routing library like React Router, one way for your component to read data from localstorage is to lazy-load it because component rendering comes first before localStorage saves the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should use state like this.

```
const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {  
      setUsername(localStorage.getItem("username"))
      setAvatar(localStorage.getItem("avatar"))
    
  
})

................
<img className="small-header-avatar" src={avatar} />
And:

<h2 className="text-center">
  Hello <strong>{username}</strong>, your feed is empty.
</h2>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... told you, it must be a noob thing that I was missing... Thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 3):

In **React**, when a component mounts

1. **states** are load
2. **UI** prints with the initial states
3. **Lifecycle hooks** run (e.g. `useEffect`) and update states
4. **DOM** re-prints with updated states

if you don't use state in your component then you should follow the above workflow to update your UI. Though I don't know what your `props.loginFlagHandler(true)` does, I am giving an example below.

```
const [isDataStored, setIsDataStored] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", {username, password});

    if (response.data) {
      // if response contains token, set login flag to true
      props.loginFlagHandler(true);

      // save user token, username, avatar in localstorage
      localStorage.setItem("username", response.data.username);
      localStorage.setItem("loginToken", response.data.token);
      localStorage.setItem("avatar", response.data.avatar);
    }
    setIsDataStored(true)
  }
}, [])
```

you can also try **lazy loading** your child component.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time and replying  in such detail @miraj... I'm a beginner in react and your answer has led me to explore **lazy loading** in detail... Thanks once again.